# Different flags count in page title and site itself in moderator dashboard if you choose to ignore time filter

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/dashboard?filtered=false

If you chose to ignore time filter, the flags count on site and page title are different.

> [image]